# Cannot connect to remote EJB deployed on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, remote-access

I'm trying to execute an EJB remote method in a JavaFX standalone application but the application hangs indefinitely. This remote EJB is deployed on a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 full profile server running in an Amazon AMI - EC2 instance with an elastic IP associated with it.

This is the code to call the remote EJB on the client application:

```
Properties configuracion = new Properties();
configuracion.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
configuracion.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","ec2-54-213-19-89.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com");
configuracion.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
contexto = new InitialContext(configuracion);
ejb = (T) contexto.lookup(nombre);
```

The application just hangs on the lookup method. No exception thrown, no timeout happening, just hangs until the java process is stopped. I've no idea why this is happening. I used Wireshark to see if there was any sort of communication between the server and the client;  i saw two packets (request and reply) that showed me that the client can indeed reach the server an so forth.

The code works on a local glassfish installation and on an internal network environment, so i think the issue should be with the EC2 environment, but i have no clear idea what could be causing this indefinite hanging. The EC2 instance has the port 3700 open to receive connections, so i don't think this is the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any resolution of the problem